# Database design with 2 m2m relationships

Tags: python, database, django, database-design

I'd like some advice on how to further develop my models and tables.

This model currently allows me to save option that links to disease and state in a m2m relationship. How would I further build this out if I wanted to save outcome and it's associated value that links to state, disease, AND option?

For example, outcome will have specific options associated to it. Options will a specific state which will have a specific disease linked to it. For every outcome linked to specific options, there will be a value assigned to it.

I think I need an intermediate table because of the outcome value the user will assign to it. I'm confused as how to link outcome to option,since option is m2m.

```
class Option(models.Model):
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Outcome(models.Model):      
   disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
   outcome = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class DiseaseState(models.Model):
   state = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
   option = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
   #outcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, blank=True) #will adding this solve my use case? It does not seem like outcome will link to option.
```

**Update:**

For some clarity: A Disease has a DiseaseState. A DiseaseState has an Option. An Option has Outcomes. Outcome has a value assigned to it. Both Option and Outcomes are lists and the user gets to pick from the list.

Comment: OK, looks like your design is done then. If any of those "has a" relationships are m2m, then the join tables will be created for you, and you're off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I follow, but you have a few options here.

The first is to manually create the intermediate table between Outcome and DiseaseState

```
class DiseaseStateOutcome(models.Model):
    unique_together = (('disease_state', 'outcome'),)

    disease_state = models.ForeignKey(DiseaseState)
    outcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)

    #option foreign key, or m2m relation to option here
```

Your other option is, if you just want a single option relating to a DiseaseState/Outcome pair, is to just put a ForeignKey from Outcome to Option.

```
class Outcome(models.Model):
    #Your other fields here
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

Comment: I think I'll try out your first option. Will I need to define a 'through' table in DiseaseState? Also, how does this intermediate table link with Option? A Disease has a DiseaseState, which has an Option. An Option has an Outcome and an Outcome has a value assigned to it. Hope that brings in a little clarity

Comment: I don't think so, since the first option serves the functionality of a m2m table.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see your whole class structure (Disease?, State?) I can't get too specific, but I'll try to talk a little about DB design.

I have a table that holds people, and I want to know their names, and what kind of car(s) they drive:

```
tbl_person
id int(11)
name varchar(32)
```

Now I could put a car column in the person table, but some people drive more than one car. So I'll make a table with cars in it, and connect (or relate) each car with a person.

```
tbl_car
id int(11)
car_name varchar(32)
person_id int(11)
```

That way each row in the car table would have a person.id. This is a `Foreign Key` relationship.

Now the problem with this is that I'm going to have a bunch of columns in my car table that have duplicate data, because there will be lots of Toyotas in there, for example.

It would be better if I had every car make in a table, and every person in another with a **join table** between them.

So I now have `tbl_person_car`:

```
id int(11)
car_id int(11)
person_id int(11)
```

Notice that each row in this table contains only two `Foreign Keys` or `FKs`.
It's really important that this join table contain **nothing** but the `FKs` needed to perform the join. Failure to do so would jeopardize the **referential integrity** of the whole database.

Of course, Django builds this join table for you whenever you employ a ManyToMany field in your model. So you never have to worry about it (which is nice, because one wrong move can ruin everything).

OK, sorry if that was too elementary, but I hope it explains that if you think your join table needs more data in it, then you've probably got an issue with your design.

I would suggest really getting comfortable with what your **models** are doing, and don't worry so much about the DB. When I started with Django, I was thinking from the DB side too much, and it caused a bit of pain.

So in your case, ask yourself, "What does a disease have?" You might say "a disease **has an** outcome." The **has a** relationship is vital to understand in OO design.

What is it, for example that **has an** Option? Is it a Disease, Patient, Outcome? Whatever it is, then that is probably the model to which an Outcome belongs.

Is this making sense?
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. To clarify the state class structure is DiseaseState that is listed above and the Disease class is just a list of diseases. I think an intermediate table will be necessary here because I have a value associated with an outcome. I'm thinking that I need to link outcome to option since an option HAS an outcome.